# Using vpa in exponential in MATLAB to prevent inf and NaN

Tags: matlab, largenumber

I am trying to plot phi vs vg in matlab for different values of Cox. I am working with extremely large values and have included them in the code here. Running the code gives Z and c0 as inf and c1 as NaN. I tried using vpa but still ended up in with the same problem.

```
e = sym(1.60217662*10^-19);
kB = sym(physconst('Boltzmann'));
T = sym(300);
Eg = sym(1.5*e); % value between 0eV and 2eV for CNT 
m = sym(0.275/e);
A = sym(0.63);
gamma = sym(3.1*e);
a = sym(2.46*10^-10); 
X = exp(Eg/2*kB*T) + A*exp(Eg/2*kB*T);
Y = exp(Eg/2*kB*T) + A*exp(m*Eg/2*kB*T);
Z = ((A)*(exp(vpa((4*m + 1)*Eg/2*kB*T,100)))*((kB*T - m*Eg)) + (exp(vpa((m+1)*Eg/kB*T,100)))*((kB*T + m*Eg)));
Cox = (264.96)*10^-12; % in S.I. Units
N0 = (8/a)* (Eg + kB*T)/(Eg + 4*gamma) * sqrt(kB*T/3*pi*Eg);
c0 = (Cox*X*[Cox*((kB*T)^2)*(Y^3) + (e^2)*N0*Z] / [Cox*kB*T*(X^2) + (e^2)*N0*exp(vpa((2*m + 1)*Eg/2*kB*T,100))]^2);
c1 = ((e^2)*Cox*N0*exp(vpa((2*m + 1)*Eg/2*kB*T,100))*((A^2)*exp(vpa(2*m*Eg/kB*T,100)) - exp((Eg/kB*T)))/[Cox*kB*T*(exp(Eg/2*kB*T) + A*exp(vpa(m*Eg/kB*T,100)))^2 + (e^2)*N0*exp(vpa((2*m+1)*Eg/2*kB*T,100))]^2);
s = c1/c0;
t = 1/c0;
vg = sym(0.2);
phi = vg/(s*vg + t);
```

Please point me to the fault and also to how this can be corrected.

Comment: This looks like a project on MOSFETs. You already set a single value for your oxide capacitance (`Cox`) value. How do you expect to change the value if it's a fixed value?

Comment: On a side note, `NaN` means "not a number" which probably means that a value for that certain variable is either undefined or indeterminate. And if you're getting `inf` as a value, that probably means you're calculating a number that is beyond floating precision capabilities. Something in your formula is not correct.

Comment: It is actually a project on CNTFET. I am currently trying to reproduce the surface potential and gate voltage with a given value of Cox.

Comment: This is not going to fix your code, but instead of `2.46*10^-10` you should write `2.46e-10`, which will be more efficient and probably more precise.

Comment: In looking at all of the `exp(Eg/2*kB*T)` terms, my gut reaction is you meant `exp(Eg/(2*kB*T))`.